# How do I loop this

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

Pretty new to Python and am using 2.7 to script.

```
a = raw_input("Input number or decimal only")
Try:
    Y = float(a)
    print a
except ValueError:
    print "wrong input, try again"
```

I need to loop this - if the input is either alphanumeric or letters, it should ask for input again.

I can't seem to find a way to slide in a while loop in it.

(Python newbie, please be kind!)

Comment: Did you copy paste your code or re-type it? Because as is this code won't run.

Comment: Did you try enclose the whole thing in `while True:` block?

Answer (score 0):

```
correct = False
a = ""
while not correct:
    a = raw_input("Input number or decimal only")
    correct = a.isalnum()
    if not correct:
        print "wrong input, try again"
print a
```

Comment: I'm showing OP where to insert the loop only :)

Comment: That will never break from loop, what is the point of this?

Comment: Didn't read the problem close enough. Edited.

Comment: Bit better. Still not sure why use try / except. You also have no need to declare a="" and correct being used like that seems silly. Just make the loop depend on it?

Comment: @Tim I am going to give a +1 for readability. it reads very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

```
input = "%"    # Set to be non alphanumeric so loop starts
while not input.isalnum():
    input = raw_input("Input number or decimal only > ")
    if not input.isalnum():
        print ("Invalid Input, try again")
    else:
        print (input)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True: # Loops!
    a = raw_input("Input number or decimal only\n")
    try:
        Y = float(a)
        print a
        break # Interrupts the loop if the input was a number
    except ValueError:
        print "wrong input, try again"
```

'while True' loops forever, the only way to stop it is 'break' within the loop

Comment: Aah, thank you!
I figured it would something easy. Appreciate the help :)

Comment: No problem! Ask if you need anything else